# How do I install Android SDK in Ubuntu 9.04?

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, java

What steps can I follow to successfully install Android SDK, Eclipse, etc. on Ubuntu 9.04? I am new to Ubuntu, so if you could keep it simple, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: [You really don't need us](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have read the information on Android.com ?

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Look at the bottom of the page all the information is available there.

Answer (score 1):

Android is a good framework and Android team have wasted many times for developing a very good documentation.
[You can find it here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)